# How to rank row values (float values)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In python, how to create Sales_rank column, values from 100 to 1.

```
if Sales_2019 <= 0.00371665 then Sales_rank =100 ;

else if Sales <= 0.0071706859 then Sales_rank =99 ;
else if Sales <= 0.0122105282 then Sales_rank =98 ;

.....

else if Sales <= 0.9602417519 then Sales_rank =2 ;
else if Sales > 0.9602417519 then Sales_rank =1 ;
```

Any precious approach to handle float values using <= (lesser than equal) ?

Comment: Hi Vannan, It will be more helpful if you can add some more information to your question. If you're unsure, please read the guidelines on [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: We're lacking some basic information here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to rank a list of floating point values, then this might work for you:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata

n = 100 # Number of Ranks/Data points
sales = np.random.rand(n) # create random values between 0 and 1 of size n as fake sales

# Rank the data, reverse the order (highest Sale is lowest (=best) rank) 
# and convert it to integer/list    
sales_order = rankdata([-1 * sale for sale in sales]).astype(int).tolist() 


for rank in range(n,0,-1): # count backwards from 100
    print("Sale: {:5.4f} makes rank {:d}".format(sales[int(sales_order.index(rank))], rank))
```

Now `sales[int(sales_order.index(rank))]` may look confusing at first. `Sales_order` is a list that contains the ranking of all `n` Sales. Since sales are in no particular order, neither are their associated rankings. It looks for the index of rank 100 first, then the index of rank 99 and so on. It returns the sale of the according rank. The rest is just formatting it nicely to get output like this for `n = 10`

```
Sale: 0.1087 makes rank 10
Sale: 0.2955 makes rank 9
Sale: 0.3214 makes rank 8
Sale: 0.3531 makes rank 7
Sale: 0.4374 makes rank 6
Sale: 0.4744 makes rank 5
Sale: 0.5143 makes rank 4
Sale: 0.5892 makes rank 3
Sale: 0.7534 makes rank 2
Sale: 0.9390 makes rank 1
```

You need numpy and scipy installed in your python environment.